# unwanted navigation bar resizing issue (CSS and HTML)

Tags: html, css, resize, navigationbar

I have built a navigation bar using HTML and CSS and it functions almost perfectly. The issue is that when either of the two gallery pages is selected, the positioning of the navigation bar moves slightly upward. Im not sure where the issue lies (it seems quite specific since I cant find any similar issue here nor on Google).

NOTE: the gallery HTML page has CSS content specifically written in because if this content is included using PHP's include statment (as on other pages), the gallery slideshow images get distorted/streched for some reason. Either way though, the navigation bar issue is present.

HTML for services page (a non-gallery pager):

```
<?PHP

//if browser is IE, displays IE specific navbar
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== FALSE)
   {include('navbarIE.php');}
//if browser is anything else, include original navbar file
else
   include('navbar.php');

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
    <title>Daiko Construction Remodeling</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div#wrapper {
            position: relative;
            margin-left: 0px;
            margin-right: 0px;
            top: 20px;
            width: 866px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <br/>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <p>For your conveniece, we have listed just a few of the projects that we most commonly undertake. 
          If there is a specific service that you require and it is not listed below, 
          please <a style="color: white;" href="contactus.php">contact us</a> for more information. Additionally, 
          we offer FREE estimates for our services. While larger projects may require us to do an on-site 
          evaluation and no two projects are exactly alike, we request that you send us a short email with 
          an inquiry or any question you might have. 
    <br><br>
    </span>
        <ul>
            <li>Window and door installation (European and Domestic)</li>
            <li>General and central HVAC, A/C, heating</li>
            <li>Remodelling of:</li>
            <ul>
                <li>kitchens</li>
                <li>bathrooms</li>
                <li>bedrooms</li>
                <li>basements</li>
                <li>etc.</li>
            </ul>
            <li>Flooring (wood and tile)</li>
            <li>House additions</li>
            <li>Lighting and electrical work</li>
            <li>Plumbing<br></li>
            <li>Regular handyman work</li>
            <li>And many others</li>
        </ul>
        <br>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?PHP include('footer.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML for gallery page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
    <title>Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='jsddm.css'>
    <img src="./styles/icons/kitchen2.jpg" class="image" />
    <style type="text/css">
        div#wrapper {
            position:relative;
            margin-left:0px;
            margin-right:0px;
            top: 14px;
            width: 866px;
        }
        /*
         //css to adjust properties of IE navigation bar and all text
        */ 
        ul.jsddm, ul.flyout {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         line-height: 2.0em;
         list-style-type:none;
        }
        ul.jsddm li {
            float: left;
            width: 20%;
            position:relative;
        }
        ul.jsddm a {
            color: #000000;
            background-color: #F5DEB3;
            border: 1px solid #444;
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-align: center;
            width: auto;
        }
        ul.flyout li {
            width: 100%;
            display:block;
            float:none;
        }
        ul.jsddm a:hover {
            color: #000;
            background-color: #FFF;
        }
        ul.flyout {
            display:none;
            position:absolute;
            top:38px;
            left:0px;
            width:100%;
        }
        ul.jsddm li:hover ul.flyout {
            display:block;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- Start WOWSlider.com HEAD section -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine1/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- End WOWSlider.com HEAD section -->

</head>
<link rel="shortcut icon"  href="./styles/icons/daikofavicon.ico" />

<body background="./styles/icons/background4.jpg">
    <body style="background-image:url(./styles/icons/background4.jpg)">

    <!--
        //navigation bar menu set up
    -->
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <ul class="jsddm">
            <li><a href="index">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="services">SERVICES</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery">GALLERY</a></li>
            <li><a href="window">WINDOWS</a></li>
            <li><a href="contactus">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Start WOWSlider.com BODY section -->
        <div id="wowslider-container1">
            <div class="ws_images">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="data1/images/img_1214.jpg" alt="Living and Dining Rooms" title="Living and Dining Rooms" id="wows1_0"/></li>
                    <li><img src="data1/images/100_2885.jpg" alt="100_2885" title="100_2885" id="wows1_1"/></li>
                    <li><img src="data1/images/img_3676.jpg" alt="Kitchen" title="Kitchen" id="wows1_2"/></li>
                    <li><img src="data1/images/img_3698.jpg" alt="Living Room" title="Living Room" id="wows1_3"/></li>
                    <li><img src="data1/images/100_2891.jpg" alt="100_2891" title="100_2891" id="wows1_4"/></li>
                    <li><img src="data1/images/dsc05866.jpg" alt="Living Room" title="Living Room" id="wows1_5"/></li>
                    <li><img src="data1/images/100_2888.jpg" alt="100_2888" title="100_2888" id="wows1_6"/></li>
                    <li><img src="data1/images/img_1224.jpg" alt="Basement" title="Basement" id="wows1_7"/></li>
                    <li><img src="data1/images/img_1246.jpg" alt="Bathroom" title="Bathroom" id="wows1_8"/></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="ws_bullets">
                <div>
                    <a href="#" title="Living and Dining Rooms"><img src="data1/tooltips/img_1214.jpg" alt="Living and Dining Rooms"/>1</a>
                    <a href="#" title="100_2885"><img src="data1/tooltips/100_2885.jpg" alt="100_2885"/>2</a>
                    <a href="#" title="Kitchen"><img src="data1/tooltips/img_3676.jpg" alt="Kitchen"/>3</a>
                    <a href="#" title="Living Room"><img src="data1/tooltips/img_3698.jpg" alt="Living Room"/>4</a>
                    <a href="#" title="100_2891"><img src="data1/tooltips/100_2891.jpg" alt="100_2891"/>5</a>
                    <a href="#" title="Living Room"><img src="data1/tooltips/dsc05866.jpg" alt="Living Room"/>6</a>
                    <a href="#" title="100_2888"><img src="data1/tooltips/100_2888.jpg" alt="100_2888"/>7</a>
                    <a href="#" title="Basement"><img src="data1/tooltips/img_1224.jpg" alt="Basement"/>8</a>
                    <a href="#" title="Bathroom"><img src="data1/tooltips/img_1246.jpg" alt="Bathroom"/>9</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="wsl"><a href="http://wowslider.com">jQuery Slideshow</a> by WOWSlider.com v4.0</span>
            <div class="ws_shadow">
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/wowslider.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/script.js"></script> 
        <!-- End WOWSlider.com BODY section -->

    </div>
    <?PHP  include('footer.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: "Vijaya", "Andalus", Serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    width: 866px;
    margin: auto;
    align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
ul.jsddm {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 2.0em;
}
ul.jsddm a {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #F5DEB3;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    height: 32px;
}
ul.jsddm a:hover {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 32px;
}
ul.jsddm > li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    width: 20%;
}
```

HTML file for navigation bar that gets included on most pages for code reuse:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='jsddm.css'>
    <img src="./styles/icons/kitchen2.jpg" class="image" />
</head>
<body background="./styles/icons/background4.jpg">
    <body style="background-image:url(./styles/icons/background4.jpg)">
</body>

    <!--
     //include favicon for site
    -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon"  href="./styles/icons/daikofavicon.ico" />

    <!--
        //jQuery to make navigation bar work and drop down 
    -->

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){

          $("ul.jsddm li").hover(function(){
            $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');        
             }, function(){
            $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');        
             });
           });
    </script>

    <!--
        //navigation bar menu set up referenced by css file jsddm
    -->
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <ul class="jsddm">
            <li><a href="index">HOME</a>
            <li><a href="services">SERVICES</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery">GALLERY</a></li>
            <li><a href="window">WINDOWS</a></li>
            <li><a href="contactus">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have some `meta` and `title` tags WITHIN your `body` tag. This HTML code is invalid. You also use the same `id` attribute on several DOMElements, which is also w3c invalid and should be avoided. Uses classes instead! Please specify a `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` ! See [Your website validation report](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fuserpages.umbc.edu%2F~daniel10%2Ftest%2Fgallery&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) Fix your website structure before working on its layout/look.

Comment: Wow, I was unaware that there were so many issues. I'll fix what I can and report back. BTW, I do not see where the meta and title tags are within the body tag.

Comment: No problem sir. [**Take a look at this**](http://i.imgur.com/0YKtHuG.jpg) to find the `meta` and `title` tags

Comment: I would agree with Jeff here, you need to reduce navigation bar that gets included not to have `<html>` `<head>` and `<body>` tags, that would rule out issues with browsers trying to handle the invalid HTML markup.

Comment: Am I reading this right? Do you have two `<body>` blocks?

Comment: @JeffNoel I didnt notice that the content of the navigation bar file that I included with PHP at the beginning gets throw into the body of file. I'll work on fixing it as well as changing the id attribute to a class attribute. Also, removing the <!DOCTYPE HTML> tag helped fix the issue. It was unnecessary in the file for the nav bar (for some reason, it added some spacing between the banner and the nav bar).

Comment: @DravSloan I removed almost all of the redundant HTML, HEAD, and BODY tags. I didnt realize that they were unnecessary in the file. I will work on removing the last two body tags in away that wont force me to include the background image in every page.

Comment: @nullability Yes, I have to body tags. I read on w3schools site that the old way of including a background using the body tag was going to be deprecated so I tried this method in an effort to make the site backwards compatible with older browsers (im still a novice at coding HTML/CSS/etc so I may have been wrong in this assumption). I'll work on fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigation bar's wrapper has a different style on your gallery page.

On the other pages you have `top: 20px;` set. On the gallery page you have `top: 14px;` set.

Just use one external style sheet across all pages for things like your navigation bar. You can get into specifics for each page in individual style sheets if necessary, but this way you will avoid inconsistencies in your "master" elements.

Comment: I changed the pixel settings to match on all pages and the problem still persists. I will work on moving the style settings to the external CSS file as well as correcting the issues outlined in the comments of my post to see if they clear anything up.

Comment: I fiddled around a little more and realized that <!DOCTYPE HTML> was throwing off the spacing. After I deleted it from the navigation bar file that gets included in all the pages except the gallery ones, the issue went away. Im a little baffled because I tried a similar solution earlier but had no luck. The only issue that remains now is that within IE, the text is not centered in the nav bar menus when the uses is on a gallery page (FF doesn't have this issue)

Comment: You are still seeing problems in IE because you don't declare a `<!doctype>` or `<html>` until well after you include your css file in your code (the css file is linked near the top, the doctype is near the middle). IE doesn't know what to do before the doctype is declared, so it skips the css file and everything else that comes before the doctype. Make sure your html is valid on your pages and these problems will clear up.

Comment: Ok, I've fixed the issue by including the CSS file at the same point on all the pages. I will keep your suggestions in mind in the future. Thanks again for the expertise!